# Find the principal axes $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ diagonalizing the quadratic form $q = x_{1}^{2} + 8x_{1}x_{2} + x^{2}_{2} $

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Find the principal axes $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ diagonalizing the quadratic form $q = x_{1}^{2} + 8x_{1}x_{2} + x^{2}_{2} $. Please explain how to find the principle axis.

Comment: This is not a tricky question, so can you please show your work, so that we can help you to get this done.

Comment: This is a relatively standard exercise in eigenvalues of symmetric matrices. Please explain what kind of difficulties you had in applying the theory. Surely an example was done either in class or in your textbook.

Comment: $q = \frac {5}{2} (x_1 + x_2)^2 - \frac{3}{2}(x_1-x_2)^2$

Comment: In other words, please study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) and improve the question. We don't look kindly at attempts to outsource homework, and you should make a bit of effort to dispel such thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. What is the matrix representing the quadratic function? In other words, what is the real symmetric matrix you are working with?
2. How do you diagonalize it?